# How to create embedded image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

Can you embed an image in Photoshop CS6 so that when you make a hyperlink the image will display on other computer screens, not just on my own? If so, how?

Comment: Hi zeeborg, Welcome to GD.SE! Can you please clarify your question and what you're trying to do? Is the hyperlink an image that will be on the web? Or are you trying to have the same Photoshop document open on 2 computers?

Comment: Using the slice tool, I can link an image for someone to click on. However, when I click on the HTML file that is created, I can see the image because there are support files on my desktop. The problem is, anyone else cannot see the image, therefore they get a broken image symbol. I need the image to be embedded so that doesn't happen.

Comment: Are you hosting the code/images on a server? I am confused on how you're presenting the file/images to another person.

Comment: My client wants me to make an ad for them. They want it digitally interactive. I made a test ad for them in photoshop cs6. Single layer file with the whole 2x1 image linking to my own website to show them how it works. Problem is, when I send the test file to them, they see only a broken link image, but it still links to my site when they click on it. The broken link is due to it wanting to link to the support image that I used to create the photoshop file. I don't know HTML. I only know how to make the link live in an indesign PDF, but not in photoshop.

Comment: How is the final ad viewed by someone? Is this going to be an interactive PDF? Email Ad? On a website?

Comment: This will be placed in an ad space on a website. The specs were given to me by the website to make it an interactive JPEG, 2" wide x 1" high, RGB, 300dpi. All I need to know is how to embed the image (it's all a single image/layer...I created it in InDesign, saved it as a PDF, then opened the PDF in photoshop. Then I sliced the whole image and assigned it a URL to link to. But it's not embedding the image. The link works. But the image doesn't display...just a little broken image thingy displays.

Comment: Just design the image based on the specs and send the client the jpg image. You don't need to make the image "have a hyperlink". That is done when the image is placed on the website and given a reference link. That is not for you to do.

Answer (score 2):

**Images** can not contain hyperlinks.

Hyperlinks are created by markup *around* an image, i.e. text.

For example, this would be a standard HTML link using an image:

> <a href="mylink.html"><img src="myimage.jpg"></a>

The image is surrounded by markup (code) designed to perform some action.

Internally Photoshop doesn't really have any way to generate such markup merely by saving an image. It *requires* saving HTML and the image at a minimum.

You might take a look at [Saving Slices with Photoshop](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/html-options-slices.html) from the Adobe Help Center.

**Essentially, you need to build the construction *around* an image. You can't make the image itself link to anything.**

Comment: Using the slice tool, I can link an image for someone to click on. However, when I click on the HTML file that is created, I can see the image because there are support files on my desktop. The problem is, anyone else cannot see the image, therefore they get a broken image symbol. I need the image to be embedded so that doesn't happen.

Comment: @zeeborg Then you need to upload the image to a web server and link to it there. In most cases, users local systems are *not* set up to allow everyone in the world to access the files on them for security reasons. Unless you are personally using your computer as a web server, there is no way for anyone else to view an image residing on your local computer.

Comment: This ad will be placed on a website's ad space for my client. Do I just supply the support files to the website in order that they can take it from there? Because I can't do that.

Comment: @zeeborg I would have no idea. I don't know your client, their resource, their business structure or even really what you are creating.